# Ubuntu Server / Apache not listening to port 443

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, ubuntu-16.04, certbot, port-443

I'm having trouble reaching my site through https after executing the certbot script. That process finished without issues, the message was:

```
Congratulations, you have succesfully enabled https://chiloexpress.ddns.net
```

However, when I test my configuration at SSLlabs, the error message says:

```
Assessment failed: Unable to connect to the server
```

When I try to access my site with normal http there is no problem, however with https there's connection timeout, according to https://check-your-website.server-daten.de/?q=chiloexpress.ddns.net.

My 000-default-le-ssl.conf file says:

```
  GNU nano 2.5.3                                                File: 000-default-le-ssl.conf                                                                                                      

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
ServerName chiloexpress.ddns.net
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chiloexpress.ddns.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chiloexpress.ddns.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

And my ports.conf says:

```
Listen 80
Listen 443
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

The result of netstat is like this:

```
netstat -tulpen | grep 443
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          2577130     8017/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          2577126     8017/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          2575983     8017/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          2575979     8017/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      0          2575975     8017/apache2
```

What could be the problem? I've restarted the service and that doesn't change anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: a timeout usually points toward a firewall problem.

Comment: Sometimes a previous apache server process keeps hanging when restarting the service. Stop de service, killall apache2, start the service to be absolutely certain.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I thought so too, yet the status of ufw says 443 is allowed:
~~~
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  

443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             

~~~

Comment: That's not the only place where a firewall can be. Check if your hoster has a firewall in front of your server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider You are correct, it was a firewall rule from the hosting provider. Thanks for your guidance ;)